# Why I am getting wrong answer here?

Tags: c

IN Codemarshal (algo.codemarshal.org) online judge there is a problem and i am getting wrong answer for this problem every time. the problem is given below

#### Problem Statement:

> CPU: 1s
> Memory: 1024MB
>
> So here is the deal, given an integer n, print all integers from 0 to n in increasing order.
>
> **Input**
> Input begins with a positive integer T, number of test cases. T lines follow, each containing a single integer, n.
>
> **Output**
> For each test case produce a line containing single space separated values from 0 to n in ascending order.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 2
> 1
> 5
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> 0 1
> 0 1 2 3 4 5
> ```

#### My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int t;
    long long int n,i;

    scanf("%d",&t);

    while( t-- ){
            scanf("%lld",&n);

            for( i = 0; i <= n; i++ ){
                printf("%lld",i);

                if( i != n )
                    printf(" ");
            }

            printf("\n");
     }
}
```

Comment: Check the return values from `scanf`

Comment: What problems do you have with your code? What unexpected (I guess) output do you actually get, and what should you get?

Comment: What is the "wrong answer" that you are receiving?

Comment: some of these online judge sites are very pedantic, so it is possible that it requires the missing `return 0;` at the end of main, which is not required by the standard. Is a limit of the numbers given? Your code is not efficent for large numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This is more efficient for printing the values:

```
printf("0");
for ( i=1; i < n; i++ ) {
   printf(" %ld", i ):
}
printf(" %ld\n", n);
```

But the desired "correct" answer might need a check for input errors (entering a non-number for any of the inputs, or an EOF), and also checking for t=0 or n=0, and checking for negative numbers.